# Should I reuse encapsulated constants when unit testing and how?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, qunit

So, I am writing a unit test for a function.
The technical details are not important, but I wanted to share some code for clarity.
Here is the function:

```
export function getSalutations(lang: Salutation = Salutation.default): string[] {
    return SALUTATIONS[lang] || SALUTATIONS.default;
};

export const enum Salutation {
    de,
    es,
    default
};
const SALUTATIONS = {
    de: ['Hr.', 'Fr.'],
    es: ['Sr.', 'Sra.'],
    default: ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.']
};
```

An example for unit test:

```
QUnit.module('getSalutations', (hooks) => {
    QUnit.test('null / default salutations', (assert) => {
        assert.ok(DW.Utils.isEqual(DW.Utils.getSalutations(null), ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.']));
    });
});
```

I do not want to copy the data like this, in order to test the method. I would like to reuse `SALUTATIONS` for my tests, so there is no redundant code. The problem is I can not use it, because it is not exported from the scope it lives in, so I have no way to access it.

So I am put before the following choices:

1. I have to copy code as mocked data.
2. I have to expose encapsulated code just for unit tests

I am not happy with both, so I hope someone can tell me what would be an optimal solution. Maybe there are other options, which I can not figure out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question may be closed for subjectivity reasons, but I'll answer anyway.

Your code is a place for abstractions.

Your tests are a place for concretions.

What this means is that if you are testing that the application will write `Hello Mr Smith` by default, and `Hallo Herr Smith` for German - you should have those strings in your test, because they are concrete examples of the expected output.

If you construct the strings for the test using the `SALUTATIONS` object, I can do this without breaking any tests:

```
const SALUTATIONS = {
    de: ['Hr.', 'Fr.'],
    es: ['Sr.', 'Sra.'],
    default: ['Whatever.', 'I quit.', 'I hate my job.']
};
```

Comment: So in brief, your point is: use mocked values? What is wrong with the second example where you use the `SALUTATIONS` object and you change it without breaking tests? Would you want them to break?

Comment: I would use the real SALUTATIONS within the code under test. My tests would have hard-coded expectations (i.e. would _not_ use SALUTATIONS). The problem with the example I gave is that if I can change SALUTATIONS without a test failing, customers will get angry.

Answer (score 3):

Some may argue this is an opinion-based question (as @Fenton suggests), but I see your dilemma, many in the JS world have it. My advice is to repeat the values in your test. You need to determine what you are testing... and it seems like what you are testing is that those values will come back from the `getSalutations` method. If that's the case then you can test three things:

1. that an array is in fact returned,
2. that there is at least one entry (or 2 or 20) in that array,
3. and that there are specific values in that array.

So now you have to decide which of those you want to test, and if it's the third (in which case it really is all three), then you should be repeating the values in your test. If someone adds a new value, then your test should be updated because it may be an *invalid* value.

Just my 2 cents.